# laravel-push-notification return html tag in response body

Tags: php, laravel, ionic-framework, push-notification

I'm using `davibennun/laravel-push-notification` for sending notification. 
When I call the notification method and return `$push->getFeedback();` from my api, I get `<html></html>` tag in response body and don't get any notification on my device. 

Here is my api method:

```
public function sendnotif(Request $request)
{
    $push = PushNotification::app('appNameIOS')
                    ->to($request['deviceToken'])
                    ->send('Hello World, i`m a push message');
    return $push->getFeedback();
}
```

and in ionic `app.js` file:

```
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function(event, notification) {
    if(ionic.Platform.isIOS()){
      console.log('ios');
      if (notification.alert) {
        navigator.notification.alert(notification.alert);
      }
      if (notification.sound) {
        var snd = new Media(event.sound);
        snd.play();
      }
      if (notification.badge) {
        $cordovaPush.setBadgeNumber(notification.badge).then(function(result) {
          console.log('badgeResult');
          console.log(result);
        }, function(err) {
          console.log('badgeResult');
          console.log(err);
        });
      }
    }
    else if(ionic.Platform.isAndroid()){
      console.log('android');
      switch(notification.event) {
        case 'registered':
          if (notification.regid.length > 0 ) {
            alert('registration ID = ' + notification.regid);
          }
          break;
        case 'message':
          // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model from the push server
          alert('message = ' + notification.message + ' msgCount = ' + notification.msgcnt);
          break;
        case 'error':
          alert('GCM error = ' + notification.msg);
          break;
        default:
          alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
          break;
      }
    }
    else{
      console.log('can not detect device');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours searching, I finally found the solution.
Now in my `api` I return result of notification with `getAdapter()->getResponse()` with this lines of code:

```
    foreach ($push->pushManager as $push) {
        $response = $push->getAdapter()->getResponse();
    }
    return var_dump($response);
```

This code returns you array of device tokens that not valid so if your result array is empty, that means all notifications was sent. 

 Also on my ionic app I had some js error. After fix them, I get notifications successfully on device.